Vue slots within a loop for a slider component
I'm having a bit of trouble working out how to use slots for a SliderA component.
SliderA component looks like the following with slides being an array prop.
<template>
    <div class="slider-container" ref="container">
        <div class="viewport" ref="viewport">
            <div class="slider" ref="slider">
                <div v-for="(slide, index) in slides" :key="index" class="slide">
                    <slot :name="`example-${slide._id}`"></slot>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

And on the page itself I am doing the following:
<SliderA :slides="data.homePage.featuredGenres">
    <template v-for="genre in data.homePage.featuredGenres" v-slot:[`example-${genre._id}`] :key="genre._id">
        <div class="genre">
            ...
        </div>
    </template>
</SliderA>

This seems to be working but I have a few concerns.

It breaks if I put the :key on the <div class="genre"></div> element within the template loop. The error states the key must be placed on the template tag. Confusing.

I am passing in the data (an array of objects) to the component as a prop :slides="data.homePage.featuredGenres" in order to loop through the slots within the component which feels unnecessary but can't work out another way to do it.


UPDATE
I tried the following which seems to work but feels like there's a simpler way. Plus, the CSS within the  component don't render (or flash off) on load. I think this would require a minimal reproduction but might just have to try and make it less efficient.
<SliderA :slides="data.homePage.featuredGenres">
    <template v-for="genre in data.homePage.featuredGenres" v-slot:[`example-${genre._id}`] :key="genre._id">
        <GenreItem :genre="genre" />
    </template>
</SliderA>


Do you use a package for the slider? You do have dynamic slot names but why? You only have a default slot so far. Regarding the removal of the extra .slide, this is a CSS thing depending on how you wanna have your stuff done, but flexbox is a safe option. As for the Vite error, what is it exactly? Also, if you have a [repro] things might go faster. Finally, what do you struggle with exactly? I assume you've read that page?

Thanks I am just updating my question with some more details.

There is no point creating dynamic slot names tbh, just keep it as an iteration because :name="`example-${slide._id}`  will not add any value to the component, this is not what slots are meant for. Overall, you don't really need any slots here IMO. If you have [object Object], it might mean that you are one level too high still or that maybe the thing you're looping on is something async? Use your Vue devtools to double-check what you have in your variable. Also, is slides defined as a prop in your component? Any warning in your browser console by any chance?

I've tidied up my question on some further findings with some specific questions. Let me know if you can :) and thanks!


It is mostly answered here, you need to put the key as told in the error indeed. 2. Again, slots are useless here but since you're expecting an array as a prop, passing such an array is the way to go. Which is both good and logical. That way, you iterate in the component on the collection yes. You should mostly only have <SliderA :slides="data.homePage.featuredGenres">, no need to have anything inside of it because you're not doing crazy things with the template but just iterating on it. Docs explain it well.



Oh wow... I did Google it but couldn't find it. This is good. 2. I'm wanting to reuse  with different content within the  in the loop.


If you want to reuse it, then use the component elsewhere with some different props. No need for a slot here as far as I understand from your needs.

The HTML of the slot is different in different uses. The component's structure is the same except for the contents of the slot. So I'm needing everything to be reused and the same except the HTML within each slide.

Then do some conditional based on the content of each object you're iterating on. For the CSS flashing, there is no apparent reason besides something async but a [repro] would indeed be needed for that one.

You need scoped slots (you pass data to the slot from its component).
And read documentation for key in v-for.
You use a default slot here, no need in named slots.
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
#="{slide: genre}" here is a shortcut for <template v-slot="{slide: genre}"> for the default slot.
<script setup>
import SliderA from './SliderA.vue';

const data = {
  homePage:{
    featuredGenres: [{name: 'Trash metal'}, {name: "Drum'n'bass"}]
  }
};
</script>

<template>
<SliderA :slides="data.homePage.featuredGenres" #="{slide: genre}">
  <div class="genre">
      {{ genre.name }}
  </div>
</SliderA>
</template>


SliderA.vue
<script setup>
defineProps({
  slides: Array
})
</script>


<template>
    <div class="slider-container" ref="container">
        <div class="viewport" ref="viewport">
            <div class="slider" ref="slider">
                <div v-for="(slide, index) in slides" :key="index" class="slide">
                    <slot :="{slide}"></slot>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


Probably totally overkill and not useful here. What's the point of using scoped slots if OP uses nothing custom in it but rather just iterates on a collection? Not sure what #="{slide}" stands for in the first snippet + you should not copy paste a solution with a key using an index from a loop. Also very curious to know why you are fine allowing custom on the fly named slots for no reason either.

@kissu from what i see, the OP wants to pass an array to a component, that renders slides and put a slide content in a slot, to use an array element in the slot we need scoped slots here. that's how it's done by the book

OP probably does not understand the point of using slots here. Naively showing a way of doing things as asked without challenging the question first is quite bad or even dangerous. It's one's responsibility to analyze the question of OP and try to see what they are trying to achieve. On another note, I would be curious to know what purpose a dynamic named slot would serve at all for a slider component. Critical answering is important. Downvotes are anonymous and to the goodwill of people voting here, they are not definitive tho. My public comments were posted above and before your question.

@kissu i understand the point, that's a clear standard slot usage as exampled in Vue docs

"from what i see, the OP wants to pass an array to a component, that renders slides and put a slide content in a slot" this is correct (I updated my question to make this clearer) @AlexanderNenashev

@AlexanderNenashev Your answer was actually exactly what I needed. It's a lot simpler too. I need to give scoped slots a re-read and also try to understand the differences. Thanks. The only issue I am experiencing is the styles <style lang="scss" scoped> within the component doesn't apply. It flashes, correctly then, then turns off.

As a reminder: begging for upvotes and acceptance is not allowed here (2nd time I inform you already). Might flag it if you continue. Also please consider focusing on people's needs more deeply rather than your points.
